# Facing error in Curl 28 connection timeout

Tags: facebook, curl

> Facebook debugger curl error: Curl error: 28 (OPERATION_TIMEOUTED)

I am using WordPress and making a new plugin to push Facebook to **scrape** my page on every URL share on FB wall. I have set time execution to 300 but still facing the same issue

```
function send_post($url, $post)
{
  
  $r = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
  curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
  curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
  $data = curl_exec($r);
  curl_close($r);
  return $data;
}

function getToken()
{
  
  $r = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token');
  curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 'client_id' => yourclinet_id, 'client_secret' => 'yourclinet_secret', 'grant_type' => 'client_credentials' ));
  curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
  $data = curl_exec($r);
  curl_close($r);
  return $data;
}
```

Facebook Debugger giving me an error -

> Curl Error
> Curl error: 28 (OPERATION_TIMEOUTED)

Comment: what´s your intention? are you trying to automatically generate an access token? because that´s not possible. and why would you let facebook scrape an url on every share? facebook automatically scrapes urls.

Answer (score 0):

Error Solved. I was calling the Curl on the same file. I have separated the curl code and issue solved. Thanks for checking